# Prove that $\sum_{n\leq x , gcd(3,n)=1} \frac{ \tau(n)}{n} = \frac{ 2(\log x)^2} {9} +O(\log x)$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

This question is from my number theory assignment and I was not able to solve it. I have been following  Analytic Number Theory by Dekonick and Luca.

> Let $\tau(n)$ be the number of divisors of n. Show that $\sum_{n\leq x , gcd(3,n)=1} \frac{ \tau(n)}{n} = \frac{ 2(\log x)^2} {9}  +O(\log x)$.

As $\tau(n) =\sum_{d|n} 1$, gcd(3,n)=1 means that n of the form 3m+1, 3m+2  ($m\in \mathbb{Z}$).

I can't change n to n=qd and then writing $\sum_{n\leq x} d(n) = \sum_{q,d , qd \leq x} 1$ because summation is only over 3n+1 , 3n+2.

So, Can you please tell how should I approach this problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be better if you think $gcd(n,3)=1$ as all $n$ which aren't the divisors of $n$.

Comment: And also  $\tau(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor$

Comment: this is similar to one of your other questions: you need to know about two things: about how the partial sums of a sequence are related to the dirichlet series of that sequence, and about euler products.

Answer (score 6):

It would be interesting if we consider the following generalized problem:

$$
F(x)=\sum_{\substack{n\le x\\(n,q)=1}}{\tau(n)\over n}
$$

To approach this, we consider studying the Dirichlet series associated to $F(x)$:

\begin{aligned}
\hat F(s)
&=\sum_{\substack{n\ge1\\(n,q)=1}}{\tau(n)\over n^s}=\prod_{p\nmid q}\left(1-{1\over p^s}\right)^{-2} \\
&=\zeta^2(s)\prod_{p|q}\left(1-{1\over p^s}\right)^2
\end{aligned}

This indicates that if we define

$$
f(n)=
\begin{cases}
\tau(n)/n & (n,q)=1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

and

$$
G(s)=\sum_{n\ge1}{g(n)\over n^s}=\prod_{p|q}\left(1-{1\over p^{s+1}}\right)^2
$$

Then we have

$$
f(n)=\sum_{n=ab}g(a){\tau(b)\over b}
$$

and

$$
F(x)=\sum_{n\le x}f(n)=\sum_{a\le x}g(a)\sum_{b\le x/a}{\tau(b)\over b}
$$

This means our task gets transformed into evaluating the inner sum. For convenience, set $z=x/a$, so that Stieltjes integration gives

\begin{aligned}
\sum_{b\le z}{\tau(b)\over b}
&=\sum_{m\le z}\frac1m\sum_{n\le z/m}\frac1n=\sum_{m\le z}\frac1m\left[\log\frac zm+\mathcal O(1)\right] \\
&=\sum_{m\le z}{\log z\over m}-\sum_{m\le z}{\log m\over m}+\mathcal O(\log z) \\
&=\frac12(\log z)^2+\mathcal O(\log z) \\
&=\frac12(\log x)^2+\mathcal O\left\{\log x(\log a)^2\right\}
\end{aligned}

Plugging this result back in, we get

$$
F(x)=\frac12(\log x)^2\sum_{a\le x}g(a)+\mathcal O\left\{\sum_{a\le x}|g(a)|(\log a)^2\log x\right\}
$$

Because for every fixed $q$, $G(s)$ converges absolutely everywhere. Therefore using the identity $G(1)=\varphi(q)^2/q^2$, we see that for every fixed $q>0$, there is

$$
\sum_{\substack{n\le x\\(n,q)=1}}{\tau(n)\over n}={\varphi(q)^2\over2q^2}(\log x)^2+\mathcal O(\log x)
$$

Plugging in $q=3$ gives exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: Where that the square on the $\log a$ term come from?

Comment: @Daniel It appears when you approximate $\sum_m\log m/m$ by the integral of $\log x/x$.

Comment: also isn't it necessary to prove that $\sum_{n > x} g(a) = O\left( \frac{1}{\log x} \right)$ to get the error term to be $O(\log x)$? Is there an easy of proving this?

Comment: @Daniel Since $\chi_{>x}(n)\le(\log n/\log x)^2$, we can see that the sum you mentioned is of $\mathcal O\{(\log x)^{-2}\}.

Comment: @Daniel By the way, you can see a lot of treatments like this in §3.4 of Montgomery & Vaughan's _Multiplicative Number Theory I: Classical Theory_.

Comment: thank you found in the book where they proved that $\sum_{n > x}g(n) \ll 1/\log x$

Comment: @Daniel My pleasure. I was astonished when I see such operation for the first time few months ago. It was this example that always pushes me to study the Euler product of Dirichlet series before actually doing the calculations.

Comment: @Travor How did you deduced that $\hat{F(s)} $ is equal to the infinite product :$\prod_{p\nmid q}\left(1-{1\over p^s}\right)^{-2}$?

Comment: @Evan Use the Euler product formula. i.e. if $f(n)$ is a multiplicative function then $$\sum_{n\ge1}{f(n)\over n^s}=\prod_p\sum_{r\ge0}{f(p)\over p^{rs}}$$

Comment: @TravorLZH I understand this theorem but how exactly $\sum_{n\geq 1, (n,q)=1} \frac{ \tau(n)}{n^s} =\prod_{p \nmid q} (1- 1/{p^s})^{-2}$. Can you elaborate on proof of this?

Comment: Let $\chi(n)$ be the characteristic function for $(n,q)=1$, then we have $\sum_{(n,q)=1}{f(n)\over n^s}=\prod_p\sum_{r\ge0}{\chi(p^r)f(p^r)\over p^{rs}}=\prod_{p\nmid q}\sum_{r\ge0}{f(p^r)\over p^{rs}}$. The right hand side follows from the fact that $\chi(p^r)=0$ when $p$ divides $q$.